# google cloud functions - permanent storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a function on Google cloud written in python that download images from firebase storage than manipulates them, there is no reason for downloading these images all over again, all I want is to download the new images, is there an option to save the downloaded images for reuse instead of downloading them over and over again?

Answer (score 8):

There is no permanent storage for Cloud Function instances, that's pretty much what you'd use Cloud Storage (or another cloud-based file/data storage option) for.

But each Cloud Functions instance does have a writeable, [local `/tmp` directory](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) that you can use for caching information between calls in that instance. Note though that the storage is backed by your Cloud Function's RAM, so you'll want to typically limit what you store in this temp storage.

Comment: Is this directory special in any way? Would it provide any advantages versus storing the same information anywhere else on the local file system? (The link provides no additional information about the `/tmp` directory.)

Comment: It looks like most of the file system is writeable these days: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment#memory-file-system. That means that it's no longer necessary to write to `/tmp`.